# ASUS WebStorage client installation?

Tags: 20.04, software-installation

It appears the Linux version of this ASUS cloud storage client has been released but with nary a word of installation instructions.  Has anyone successfully installed this set of programs and if so please share your installation instructions?

Answer (score 1):

Open `main.ini`, set `ACCOUNT` and `PASSWORD` to your login info.

Then you start it with `./webstorage_main_process start`. You can add this to your startup applications (but do use a full path).

Help is available with `./webstorage_main_process --help`.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Followed that but still have some functional questions.  I found an ASUS WS User manual but its basically GUI centric.